# Writing related and multiple functions

Tags: jquery

[image]

I write code for:

(1)

```
// Follow Button click action
$('body').on('click' , '.btn-follow', function() { 
  $(this).removeClass('btn-follow').addClass('btn-following');
  $(this).text('Following');

  // call followingHover function to get the action of that button
  followingHover();
});
```

(2)

```
// Hover on Following Button
function followingHover() {
  $('.btn-following').hover(
    function() {
      $(this).addClass('btn-unfollow');
      $(this).text('Unfollow');
    }, function() {
      $(this).removeClass('btn-unfollow');
      $(this).text('Following');
    }
  );
};

followingHover();
```

(3)

```
// Following Button click action
$('body').on('click', '.btn-following', function() { 
  $(this).removeClass('btn-following').addClass('btn-follow');
  $(this).text('Follow');
});
```

But, the problem is I can't maintain these functions together. So, inside one function other function is calling in wrong way. How can I make these set of  functions well-written? Will you please help me?

[Fiddle Demo For testing](https://jsfiddle.net/00py6vc2/3/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can check this example.
[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/00py6vc2/4/)

(1)
    
          Follow

```
    <div class="action-list-item">
      <a href="#" class="btn  btn-action btn-follow" type="button">Follow</a>
    </div>

    <div class="action-list-item">
      <a href="#" class="btn  btn-action btn-following" type="button">Following</a>
    </div>
```

(2)

```
  $(document).ready(function(){

$("body").on("mouseenter",".btn-following",function(){
$(this).text("Unfollow")
}).on("mouseleave",".btn-following",function(){
 $(this).text("Following")
})
})
// Following Button click action
$("body").on("click",".btn",function(){
if($(this).hasClass("btn-follow")){
   $(this).text("Following");
   $(this).removeClass("btn-follow").addClass("btn-following");

}else{
 $(this).text("Follow");
 $(this).removeClass("btn-following").addClass("btn-follow");
}
 })
```

(3)

```
.action-list-item {
  margin: 20px;
}

.btn-action {
  background-color: yellow;
  color: #333;
  border-color: #af932c;
  width: 86px;
}
.btn-following {
  background-color: green;

}
.btn-following:hover{
  background:red;color:white;
  content:"Unfollow";
  }
.btn-action.btn-unfollow {
  background-color: #9e3515;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! One thing I need to do: red background color should only come when "Unfollow" text will be appeared. At the fiddle when I click on the first "Follow" button, it will change to "Following" and as at the time of changing still there are cursor on that button, it shows red background-color. http://i.imgur.com/0AzFzmH.png

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/learner73/00py6vc2/7/
How about this? Only without background color there can be multiple property available at the "Unfollow" state like icon, background-image etc. Instead of adding those by Jquery every time, I prefer adding a class for the "Unfollow" state and define all the property in that class. By the way, thanks for your help. My issues have been solved finally.